# How to check and install another software requirement before your software in installshield?

Tags: installshield

I'm doing a software that requires from OpenVPN to work, so I'm expecting that when I launch the installer checks if OpenVPN is installed and if not launch it's installer. If the install is successful then continue with the install, if not, exits.
Also, I'd like to check if O.S is 32 or 64bits in order to launch the correct installer from openvpn.

How would be the best way to do that? I've readed about custom actions, nested installations, chainers, etc... but I'm newbie in this and I don't know where to start.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 with Installshild plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create "BootStrap" application (.exe) and add as prerequisite, what is running before you install starts. You also can check box ( not show in prerequisite list) and you Bootstrap app will be not in PreReq,. dialog

Comment: Thanks mate, investing on prerequisites was exactly what I needed ;)